# Spring Property Injection with Play2 Framework

Tags: java, spring, properties, playframework-2.0

I like many features of Play Framework 2 (I'm using it with Java) but, as a fan of Dependency Injection, I love also Spring and particularly, its way to inject configuration into objects by just using the `@Value` annotation.

Therefore, I would love to know how to inject into an instance variable the value of a property using Play's built-in property resolution mechanism. Something like this:

```
@Component
public class SpringBeanWithinAPlay2Application {

   @Value("${application.timeout:10}")
   private int timeout;
}
```

Any clue anyone?
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem a while ago and this was my way of making this work:

Firstly, when you boostrap your Spring Application context (I use annotation based configuration but the same should work for XML based), **you have to add a custom [PropertySource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html)**, which is the way Spring enables the addition of new way of resolving properties. Something like this:

```
public static void initialize() {
    ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
    ctx.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addFirst(new PlayFrameworkPropertySource());
    ctx.scan("somepackage");
    ctx.refresh();
}
```

The custom class `PlayFrameworkPropertySource` is the one that does the magic:

```
public class PlayFrameworkPropertySource extends PropertySource<Object> {

    public PlayFrameworkPropertySource() {
        super("Play Framework properties resolution mechanism");
    }

    @Override
    public Object getProperty(String propertyName) {
        // or ConfigFactory.load().getString(propertyName), as you prefer...
        return Configuration.root().getString(propertyName);
    }
}
```

In order for all this to work, you just need to do one more thing: **explicitly declare a bean of type [PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.html)** in some [@Configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html) class you might be using:

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

**Important Note: this bean must be `static`**, as it's a [BeanFactoryPostProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanFactoryPostProcessor.html) and it should be loaded prior to any other regular @Bean.

This worked like a charm for me, hope this is helpful to someone else!

Cheers,
Jonathan